# Partial render of Cordova app in Android web view, but not in dev tools

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-webview, ionic4

I'm experiencing a weird bug where my Cordova app sometimes doesn't fully render in the Cordova web view on android, but if I open up Chrome Dev Tools, I see the fully rendered preview.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Edit: if it helps, screwing around with some CSS properties like `font-size` makes some things render, and re-enabling them reverts them back to their partial-rendered state.

Edit 2: Confirmed it is not related to Ionic, even removing all references to ionic causes the issue.

[image: Web View and Dev Tools]

Comment: Are you using latest proper versions? If I would be you I would start with comparing your depedencies (package.json) with Ionic 4 conf reference app dependnecies. Then reinstall missing stuff. This looks like CSS and ionicons packages are missing or in bad shape.

Comment: I'm using the CDN bundle for css and js, no webpack going on. It sometimes all renders correctly after a few tries launching the app, it's not missing the css or anything like that. Also, it always renders correctly in the dev tools preview.

Comment: The point of Ionic is to have all those assets locally available;) do you have to use CDN? can you get rid of that?

Comment: I downloaded it from the CDN and am serving them locally. There aren't any issues with loading the css or js, I don't see any issues with loading the assets. There seems to be an issue at render time, and only in the actual web view, since the dev tools preview is correct.

Comment: @hmind did you find a solution to this?